# "X is less effective than y in treating the disease" or "X is less effective in treating the disease than y"?

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

Should it be,

"PT with selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors (SSRIs)is less effective than CT in treating anxiety"

or,

"PT with selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors (SSRIs) is less effective in treating anxiety than CT"

The former sounds more correct to me, but then it also feels awkward to have "in treating anxiety" outside of the comparative like that. Are both acceptable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not turn it around and put the useful information at the beginning, and the complex phrase at the end, where it's easier to process: _CT  is more effective in treating anxiety than PT with selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors (SSRIs)._

Comment: Doesn't this say the same thing? I see you opted for putting "in treating anxiety" before rather than after "than PT with selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors (SSRIs)", and this is what I was curious about. Why like this instead of putting "in treating anxiety" at the end of the sentence, as in the first sentence of my OP. This sounds more natural. Does it matter?

Relatedly, shouldn't there be an "is" at the end of the sentence?

As in, 

"CT is more effective in treating anxiety than PT is" 

or,

"CT is more effective in treating anxiety than is PT

Thanks

Comment: That's it. Use what sounds most natural to you after you ask your question and get a new approach. A better approach.

Comment: You could also consider "For treating anxiety, PT with selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors (SSRIs) is less effective than CT".

Comment: There is a nonzero chance that some reader somewhere might misunderstand the two things that you are comparing in the second wording. Is the idea that "PT with SSRIs is less effective in treating anxiety than CT is," or that "PT with SSRIs is less effective in treating anxiety than in treating CT"? For readers who don't know what CT is, the latter reading is possible. In contrast, ""PT with SSRIs is less effective than CT in treating anxiety" cannot be misread in this way. Another option might be to rework the sentence as "As a treatment for anxiety, PT with SSRIs is less effective than CT."

Comment: @JohnLawler Your version allows the parse "(CT is more effective ... than PT) with selective..." -- not grouping "with SSRI" solely with PT. Although it's possible that context and general knowledge within the field would prevent this interpretation.

Comment: @Barmar You have to figure that a scientific audience will not go out of their way to find an odd parse. Given what gets published, and the fact that any written sentence is multiply ambiguous, this is not a big concern.